# How to raise event because a user didn't not select a checkbox option after choosing a certain value in a combobox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, checkbox

I am new to vb.net and I have looked at other topics.  I cannot find the answer I need. OK I have a combobox named cboRaceDesc and five checkboxes (CkRaceAfricanAmerican, ChkRaceAmerican Indian, ckRaceAsian, ckRacePacificIslander, and ckRaceWhite).  I was going to post an image, but I cannot.

cboRaceDesc has two options...Hispanic and Other.  If the user selects Other then they have to choose one of the five checkboxes or it will raise an exception when the record is being saved.  I am assuming I would generate the code under the "save" button.  I know I need to gather the following information in my code:

```
If cboRaceDesc.SelectedValue = Other Then
<I am not sure how to code the logic regarding the checkboxes>
<I know I need to use multiple else/else if statements>
<I know towards the end I would generate the exception>
End
```

Can anyone help me fill in the blanks or point me in the right direction?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one of 5 options can be selected then you should probably use radiobutton (with same group name) or radiobuttonlist control. Quick (and dirty) verification logic would be something like this:

```
If cboRaceDesc.SelectedValue = "Other" Then

   if (CkRaceAfricanAmerican.Checked orelse 
      ChkRaceAmericanIndian.Checked orelse 
      ckRaceAsian.Checked orelse 
      ckRacePacificIslander.Checked orelse 
      ckRaceWhite.Checked) then

      ' show error message or throw exception

   End if

End if

' save stuff
```

Comment: you should also consider adding custom validator control and write this piece of code inside ServerValidate event

Comment: I am assuming in VB.net 2003 :-(.....that would be an ErrorProvider?  Yeah...I said 2003 most of my kungufu is in C# post VS2005